# Prevent Internal Server Error with Symfony 2 / Monolog on failed gelf connection

Tags: php, symfony, monolog

I'm trying to stream logs from a symfony 2 app to a graylog 2 server using the gelf format.

My monolog configuration looks as follows:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
          # --- 8< ---
          # ...
          # --- >8 --- 
          graylog:
              type: gelf
              publisher:
                  hostname: my-graylog-server.com
                  port: 12201
              level: debug
              formatter: app.gelf_formatter
```

When the graylog server is not available, I get (understandably) a connection refused error

```
[2017-07-28 16:03:25] app.ERROR: Failed to write to socket: fwrite(): send of 153 bytes failed with errno=111 Connection refused (8) [] []
```

which results in an internal server error (500 response code to the request causing the log).

What's the best way to catch this error? Having an error log is resonable, but I don't want my requests to error when the external log processing server is not available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best bet is to have a local caching mechanism on your application server to forward requests. That way if there is momentary downtime of the log server, the requests can be queued. Systems like fluentd work well for this. On the other hand, if you don't care about losing log messages, you can look into a Transport that ignores errors such as `IgnoreErrorTransportWrapper`:

https://github.com/bzikarsky/gelf-php/blob/master/src/Gelf/Transport/IgnoreErrorTransportWrapper.php

Further reading:

https://github.com/bzikarsky/gelf-php/issues/56

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the fast reply. The IgnoreErrorTransport wrapper is what I'm looking for (for now at least). Do you know how I can specify that in the symfony config?

Comment: Sorry - no clue. I haven't done symfony in 3 years. :-P