# Graylog / Symfony2 / Gelf: How to configure logger to ignore errors?

Tags: php, symfony, monolog, graylog2, gelf

I'm trying to stream logs from a symfony 2 app to a graylog 2 server using the gelf format.

My monolog configuration looks as follows:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
          # --- 8< ---
          # ...
          # --- >8 --- 
          graylog:
              type: gelf
              publisher:
                  hostname: my-graylog-server.com
                  port: 12201
              level: debug
              formatter: app.gelf_formatter
```

When the graylog server is not available, I get (understandably) a connection refused error

```
[2017-07-28 16:03:25] app.ERROR: Failed to write to socket: fwrite(): send of 153 bytes failed with errno=111 Connection refused (8) [] []
```

which results in an internal server error (500 response code to the request causing the log).

(See also this question: [Prevent Internal Server Error with Symfony 2 / Monolog on failed gelf connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45376128/prevent-internal-server-error-with-symfony-2-monolog-on-failed-gelf-connection))

gelf-php provides an [IngoreErrorTransportLogger](https://github.com/bzikarsky/gelf-php/blob/master/src/Gelf/Transport/IgnoreErrorTransportWrapper.php), which seems to be build for this exact purpose.

How can I configure this in Symfony's monolog config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that Symfony has `WhatFailureGroup` handler wrapper a handler which ignores errors from the logs of all logging handlers that it wraps.

Our config now looks like this, it just drops errors during logging (probably not ideal, but better than failing outright due to an error during logging).

```
monolog:
    handlers:
          main:
              type:         fingers_crossed
              action_level: warning
              handler:      grouped
          grouped:
              type:         whatfailuregroup
              members:      [file, graylog]
          file:
              type:         stream
              path:         "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
              level:        debug
          graylog:
              type: gelf
              publisher:
                  hostname: my-graylog-server.com
                  port: 12201
              level: debug
              formatter: app.gelf_formatter
```

Essentially we replaced `type: group` with `type: whatfailuregroup`.

Answer (score 1):

You can additionally use UDP transport in Graylog.

First you'd need to configure GELF UDP input in Graylog, then configure it like this:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        # ...
        graylog:
            type: gelf
            publisher:
                id: gelf_publisher
            nested: true

services:
    gelf_publisher:
        class: Gelf\Publisher
        arguments:
            - '@gelf_transport'
    gelf_transport:
        class: Gelf\Transport\UdpTransport
        arguments:
            - '%env(GRAYLOG_HOSTNAME)%'
            - '%env(GRAYLOG_PORT)%'
```